# Create Folders and Subfolders using VBS

Tags: vbscript, directory, subdirectory

I want to be able to create a set amount of folders and subfolders within a directory. I already have a code that loops through and creates the folders and subfolders. Is there anyway to create a set amount of these folders? Also I want to be able to create them sequentially. For example I already have 2000 folders in there. I would want to create a thousand more but it would start from 2001 to 3000.  I basically want to automate the code i have below so no one has to go in and keep changing the values in the script. Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
Dim oFSO,Folder
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For i = 1001 To 2000
 '  x=msgbox("Directorie " & i ,64, "MakeDir")

If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i) Then
  oFSO.CreateFolder i
End If
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/Text") Then
  oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/Text"
End If
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/Text") Then
  oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/Text"
End If
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/Text") Then
  oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/Text"
End If
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/TestData") Then
  oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/TestData"
End If
 Next
```

Comment: Where would you be setting the desired amount? An external input box or something?

Comment: No it would just be within the code itself. I am planning on using the Task scheduler to create these folders . So i would just want it to run on its own.

Comment: Ah, perhaps name them something like `"folder_no_" + i` then, before running your loop, parse the name of the last folder created?

Comment: Would parsing just give me the folder number? Im sorry I am completely new to programming vbs.

Comment: Sure, just strip `folder_no_` part, leaving you with the number. e.g. `mid(folder_string, 11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
BaseFolder = "C:\temp"  'Root folder to look for/create subfolders in
MaxSize = 5             'the number of characters to allow in folder name
PaddingCharacter = "0"  'padding folder names with zeros for proper sorting
NumFolders = 10         'number of additional folder to create

intStart = GetLastFolder(BaseFolder)

If IsNull(intStart) Then
    intStart = 1
Else 
    'skip
End If

For i = intStart To intStart + NumFolders
    strFolderName = BaseFolder & "\" & RightPad( i, MaxSize, PaddingCharacter )
    Wscript.Echo strFolderName
    CreateFolders(strFolderName)
Next

Function GetLastFolder(strFolder)
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(BaseFolder)   
   Set subFlds = objFolder.SubFolders

    For Each fld in subFlds
        s = fld.Name
    Next

    x=Len(s)    
    For i=0 to x-1
        If Mid(s,i+1,1) = "0" Then
            'skip
        Else
            s = Mid(s,i+1,x)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next 

   GetLastFolder = s
End Function


Function CreateFolders(i)
    Dim oFSO,Folder
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i) Then
      oFSO.CreateFolder i
    End If
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/Text") Then
      oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/Text"
    End If
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/Text") Then
      oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/Text"
    End If
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/Text") Then
      oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/Text"
    End If
    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(i & "/TestData") Then
      oFSO.CreateFolder i & "/TestData"
    End If
End Function

Function RightPad( strText, intLen, chrPad )
    'Example: RightPad( "1000", 7, "0" ) = "0001234"
    'Example: RightPad( "1000", 4, "0" ) = "1000"
    RightPad = Right( String( intLen, chrPad ) & strText, intLen )
End Function
```